# Unit Testing with Shoulda

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, shoulda

**edit: this problem only happens sometimes**

This only appears to happen when I run the test from within TextMate (even when I specify the ruby to run it from by hand with a shebang). If I run it from the terminal then everything is peachy…

---

Here's some code:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'shoulda'

class TestingTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  context "My thing" do  
    should "always have this test fail, and give me this message" do
      assert false
    end
  end
end
```

I'm expecting it to tell me something like:

```
1) Failure:
test: My thing should always have this test fail, and give me this message (TestingTest)
# etc
An assert message, if one was given
```

But I'm getting:

```
1) Failure:
test:8
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

So what am I missing? The example code above is as simple as I think I can make it and I can't see the problem!

Comment: That's not how Shoulda worked when I tried it out. Care to show us some code?

Comment: Just noticed it was working the way I expect it to (showing context and should messages when failing) with a different test — will have to investigate closer! Bear with me & thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try inheriting from `ActiveSupport::TestCase` instead of the Test::Unit::TestCase